# Listvew is not populated and getView function is also not getting called

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to `Android` programming. I'm trying Shopping cart tutorial trying to populate the `listview` of catalog view using the `productAdapter`. But the list is not getting populated and also `getview` function is not getting called. I'am attaching my files. Please let me know,where I'am going wrong.

```
ProductAdapter.java

package com.example.helloshoppingcart;

import java.util.List;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private class viewItem{
        ImageView productImageView;
        TextView productTitle;
        CheckBox productCheckbox;
    };

    private List<Product> mproductList;
    private LayoutInflater minflater;
    private Boolean mShowCheckbox;

    ProductAdapter(List<Product> productList, LayoutInflater inflater, Boolean showCheckbox)
    {
            this.mproductList = productList;
        this.minflater = inflater;
        this.mShowCheckbox = showCheckbox;              
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ){
        final viewItem item;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView  = minflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            item = new viewItem();

            item.productImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewItem);
            item.productTitle= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewItem);
            //item.productCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxSelected);
            convertView.setTag(item);
        }else{
            item = (viewItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Product prod = mproductList.get(pos);
        item.productImageView.setImageDrawable(prod.productImage);
        //item.productCheckbox.setChecked(prod.selected);
        item.productTitle.setText(prod.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}

CatalogActivity.java

package com.example.helloshoppingcart;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CatalogActivity extends Activity {
    private List<Product> mproductList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        //get the catalog and display all the records
        mproductList = shoppingCartHelper.getCatalog(getResources());
        ListView catalogListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
        ProductAdapter catalogListAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mproductList, getLayoutInflater(), false);
        catalogListView.setAdapter(catalogListAdapter);

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_catalog, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

activity_catalog.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">

    <!--<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24dip" android:layout_margin="5dip" android:text="Product Catalog"></TextView>-->
    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/ListViewCatalog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="true" android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff">
    </ListView>
    <!-- <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/ButtonViewCart"
        android:text="View Shopping Cart"></Button>-->
</LinearLayout>

item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewItem"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="100dip">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewItem"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:textSize="26dip"
    android:text="Phone Names"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxWidth="150dip">        
     </TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">        
    </TextView>

    <!-- <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip" android:id="@+id/CheckBoxSelected"
        android:focusable="false" android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </CheckBox>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

In ProductAdapter, the getCount() method returns the number of items owned by the Adapter associated with this ListView. So, it should return the maximum number of items that the listview will display i.e. the size of the list you are using as a data source : mproductList.size()
The getView() method is not getting called because this function is returning 0 in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Only took a fast glance, but getCount() should return the number of items
in the adapter, and therefore mproductList.size()